# Passing OOP Tests in Python

Tags: python, oop

I am trying to pass some tests but I am not getting a pass after coding. The assertion is saying the output is expecting a string but my code is not fulfilling the conditions but on when I run the code I am getting the required results but they the code is not passing the test.

my Code

```
class Book:
    def __init__(self, title, page_count):
        self.title = title
        if isinstance(page_count, int):
            self.page_count = page_count
        else:
            print("page_count must be an integer")
```

test fail description:

```
def test_requires_int_page_count(self):
        '''prints "page_count must be an integer" if page_count is not an integer.'''
        book = Book("And Then There Were None", 272)
        captured_out = io.StringIO()
        sys.stdout = captured_out
        book.page_count = "not an integer"
        sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
>       assert captured_out.getvalue() == "page_count must be an integer\n"
E       AssertionError: assert '' == 'page_count m... an integer\n'
E         - page_count must be an integer
```

Comment: Is it as simple as converting the number input from a string to an int?

Comment: No, when you test it yourself you don't get the required result. Do you really have code where you do `book.page_count = "not an integer"`? And does it print "page_count must be an integer" when you call that line? I don't think so. Please show how you test it.

Comment: @duffymo I think it's about properties and some kind of (not production-ready) error handling in the setter.

Comment: in `test_requires_int_page_count()` what is `self` expected to be if you create a new instance of `Book()`? If your intent is to capture the print statement in `__init()__` you need to create the new instance after setting the new buffer. At the moment, `captured_out` is empty.

Comment: Part of the problem might be that the assignment check for book count prints an error message if the parameter is not an int type, but it doesn't fail.  self.page_count is in limbo and not assigned in that case.

Comment: He’s testing the requirement that that message should be printed. The discussion of whether that’s a good requirement does not help with the technical problem here

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you're expecting `book.page_count = "not an integer"` to generate your error message.  But that's not going to happen ... your `print()` occurs in the `__init__` method, which is invoked by `Book("And Then There Were None", 272)`

So if this is the approach you want to take, you need to

1. capture stdout before you create the Book
2. have your test trigger the error

Which would look something like (I have not tested this):

```
def test_requires_int_page_count(self):
    # capture your stdout
    captured_out = io.StringIO()
    sys.stdout = captured_out

    # trigger the error
    book = Book("And Then There Were None", "not an integer")

    # put stdout back
    sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__

    # check for your message
    assert captured_out.getvalue() == "page_count must be an integer\n"
```